# How to apply the "text-indent" in paragraph?

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-indent

I have a problem with "text-indent" using css, What i want is, have paragraph with 3 or more lines, with in that i want to apply the "text-indent" style for first two lines and remaining lines will become to normal alignment. I have tried using CSS but i couldn't get the expected result, so can anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use span inside your p tag and than apply text-indent to individual elements.

Comment: @noobcode Any otherway without adding any inner elements ? if add in that, have to modify in all areas.

Comment: Not sure its possible without markup. This link might help: http://www.impressivewebs.com/how-to-put-a-multi-line-indent-on-a-styled-blockquote/

Comment: Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element with `float:left` to achieve this

```
p:before
{
    content: '';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px; /* however much you need for 2 lines */
    float:left;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/SZTLw/)**

Answer (score 0):

text-indent is used to apply space before each paragraph. So if you want to have space for the first two lines, you could either split them in two paragraphs or to encapsulate the lines in another element (div/span) and apply margin-left or padding-left, depending on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="indent">This is the first line.</br>
   This is the second Line
<p/>
<p>Those are other header or text or p or something else</p>
```

CSS

```
.indent {
   text-indent:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
<html>
<dl>
<dt><a href="http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/hanging-indents.shtml">Hanging Indents in CSS and HTML</a></dt>
<dd><p>This article describes how you can create hanging indents on your web pages using CSS and HTML.</p></dd>
<dd><p>This is second line of hanging index</p></dd>
<p>This is normal text line 3.</p>
</html>
```

for demo: http://www.compileonline.com/try_html5_online.php